# Does removing ISPConfig delete any websites on server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Does removing or uninstalling ISPConfig cause any websites on the server to get deleted or harmed  in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running the uninstall script will remove the ISPconfig database as well as Apache configuration files. Various services like mail and FTP will stop working. Just migrate your sites and services to another host that doesn’t have <strike>poison</strike> a control panel installed it.